# Fluent Design Menus in Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm currently designing a Hololens application and I'm pretty new to everything. The menu right now seems a little "old-school" for my taste. I'd like to create a user-friendly menu that could be pinned in place or move around as the user wishes.

I've been checking out fluent designs and found the DesignLab toolkit (https://unitylist.com/p/19/MR-Design-Labs-Unity) but its from 2017. Is there anything new I could use to make my menus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the PressableButton.prefab in MRTK. This aligns pretty exactly with the system style and fluent design. There's documentation here:
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Button.html

It's relatively easy to use the same materials and shaders to create a background panel for text or other things that aren't buttons.

Keep an eye out for how the shader reacts when MRTK's simulated hand approaches it. There's a lot of cool reactive fluent elements there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ButtonHolographic from the HoloToolkit Example. These are flat designed uwp buttons. Take a look at the example scenes from the holotoolkit-example.